# GeoSpatial data transformation using AWS glue (spark) / lambda (python)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a requirement where , i get the data from MS SQL Server via DMS to S3 , the data which we get is having geography datatype. where i'm trying to read parquet file which is stored in S3 , and then need to apply geospatial calculation like STArea , longituded , latitude , STbinay.
But as i see there is no direct feasibility in spark that we can read geospatil data and do transformation on it. we need to include some libraries like geopandas , some other like that.

But i see Glue is not supporting any packages to import the libraries other that the glue supported ones .

the same problem i'm trying to solve using lambda , but no luck in finding any solution .

could you please help me to get any solution for that.... let me know if anything needed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue in my account and i was able to see the same issue. When i explored further i could see the geopandas python library has further dependencies. please refer the link mentioned below.

https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__geopandas.org_install.html-23dependencies&d=DwICaQ&c=tVn-kblGR-RhQXORcY2YtK6wCF2wd5VMQ-rCGnFqBi4&r=HqX3pTDMjylpU82wpEjWr_oZEtluhFdOXuMutBkPnEM&m=4a5y4E2h1N9RhbHqRlwSOSW6EF0IKJuqjRHWNUBEYmY&s=VXMqlssz3bsKsSYvJa01RJZezkXn-_PI44gBrI7uyUc&e=

AWS team response for Glue solution :  I tried to install these dependencies in the Glue job and its not being installed due to configuration required to build these libraries. I tried to build these libraries on standalone ec2 instances as well and tried to provide them to the Glue job but no luck there seems to requirements of Cython to compile these dependencies.

At this point, I can comment these libraries are not supported out of box by Glue and even with configurations and dependencies i am not sure it will work. I can reach out to service team to check if they have any plans to support these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I find the AWS glue not a good fit because of the problem with installing binaries. But with the Lambda it could be achieved by using the Docker image. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). So for instance using the image from [osgeo](https://hub.docker.com/r/osgeo/gdal) you can install gdal, and use it for geospatial data.